# Simplification in Algebric Equation

Tags: calculus

I am confused with simplification in algebraic equation, which formula is used to simplify this equation. Please see last highlighted line.

[View Screenshot[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q4R0I.png)

Comment: $(a+b)+(c-a)=a-a+b+c=b+c$

Comment: What video course is this screenshot from?

Comment: Its Calculus Course by Virtual University you can find it on youtube but its in urdu language.

Answer (score 0):

Just open the brackets to add all the terms. The ones will cancel each other out:

$$\require{cancel}
(1+\sqrt{x-2})+(x-1)=\cancel{1}+\sqrt{x-2}+x-\cancel{1}=\sqrt{x-2}+x.
$$

Also, don't forget that you can move things around because addition is commutative:
$$
\sqrt{x-2}+x=x+\sqrt{x-2}.
$$

Comment: Thank you, well explained.